# Async Task cancellation best practices: user versus program

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm working on a library which does some lazy idle background work on a UI thread (it has to be that way because of the legacy COM use). The task can be cancelled by the consuming app via cancellation token, or it can be explicitly cancelled as a result of user action (via `IUserFeedback.Continue`). I'm trying to follow the [MSDN pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) for task cancellation.

My question is, should I make the difference between cancellation by user (and return `false`) and by the calling app (throw), as `IdleWorker1` does. Or should I treat both cases equally and just throw, as with `IdleWorker2`?

I don't have any strict requirements from the designers of the interface (the task is essentially never ending, so they only care about how much work has actually been done so far, and they're receiving the progress via `IUserFeedback.Continue`).

In a nutshell, **IdleWorker1**:

```
interface IUserFeedback
{
    bool Continue(int n);
}

class IdleWorker1
{
    public async Task<bool> DoIdleWorkAsync(CancellationToken ct, int timeSlice, IUserFeedback feedback)
    {
        bool more = true;
        int n = 0;
        while (more)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            more = feedback.Continue(++n);
            await Task.Delay(timeSlice);
        }
        return more;
    }
}
```

**IdleWorker2**:

```
class IdleWorker2
{
    public async Task DoIdleWorkAsync(CancellationToken ct, int timeSlice, IUserFeedback feedback)
    {
        int n = 0;
        for (;;)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            if (!feedback.Continue(++n))
                throw new TaskCanceledException();
            await Task.Delay(timeSlice);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you don't need to differentiate between the two types of cancellation, the canceled method shouldn't even know who canceled it.

To do that, you would have one `CancellationTokenSource` for cancellation by the app and another one for cancellation by user. You would then combine them into one using [`CreateLinkedSource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642265) and pass the token of that to the method.

Comment: This is great and I've learnt about `CreateLinkedSource()`, thank you. But that would require me to pass the new "user" cancellation token to `IUserFeedback.Continue`, right? I hope I can convince the consumer of the library to follow this pattern.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to switch to this, I think you couldn't use `IUserFeedback.Continue` anymore. With that, you periodically *ask* the user whether the method should be canceled. With CTS, the user has to *tell you* when the method should be canceled.

Comment: I still have to report on the progress (and the real progress is more than just a count). Also, I said wrong in my comment, passing the cancellation token to `IUserFeedback.Continue` wouldn't make sense, it would have to be the cancellation source itself. But I do like the idea and will recommend it to the other party.